# Me pueden ayudar a imprimir una lista de mis números ingresados

Tags: java

Esto es lo que llevo

```
int num,i,z,ab=0,si=0,no=0,su=0;
        double mi;
        do{ num=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"¿Cuantos numeros desea Ingresar?"));

        } while(num<=0);
        {for(i=1;i<=num;i++) {
            z=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingrese numero : "));

            if(z%2==0) { no++; ab=ab+z; }
            else { su++;
            } si=si+z;  
                } }
        if(no>0) { 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"La suma de los numeros pares es : "+ab);
        }
        else {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No hay numeros pares");
```

Comment: Si añades el error que te genera o el resultado que tienes al momento, va a ser más simple para la comunidad apoyarte

Comment: No hay error, pero quiero mostrar una lista de mis números ingresados en una sola ventana, antes de mostrar la suma.

Comment: Considera editar y agregar lo que buscas lograr en tu pregunta, ya que la misma no es clara pues es mayormente código, checa [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer para visualizar los números que ingresan seria crear un ArrayList y luego mostrarlo en el JOptionPane, de esta manera.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num, i, z, ab = 0, si = 0, no = 0, su = 0;
    double mi;
    ArrayList<String> nombreArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    do {
        num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "¿Cuantos numeros desea Ingresar?"));

    } while (num <= 0);
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            z = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese numero : "));
            nombreArrayList.add(z + "");
            if (z % 2 == 0) {
                no++;
                ab = ab + z;
            } else {
                su++;
            }
            si = si + z;
        }
    }
    if (no > 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los numeros ingresados son: " + nombreArrayList.toString());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La suma de los numeros pares es : " + ab);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No hay numeros pares");

    }
}
```